# ReactNative & Expo: Ionicons not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, icons, expo, ionicons

According to the docs, if I have Expo installed I don't need to do anything else besides the import statement.

My component:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"
import { MusicContext } from "../context/MusicContext"
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons"

export const MusicPlayer = () => {
  const { previousTrack, pauseAndPlay, nextTrack, isPlaying } = useContext(MusicContext)

  return (
    <View style={styles.musicPlayerContainer}>
      <View style={styles.controls}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.control} onPress={previousTrack}>
          <Ionicons name="md-skip-backward" size={24} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.control} onPress={pauseAndPlay}>
          {isPlaying ? (
            <Ionicons name="md-pause" size={24} color="black" />
          ) : (
            <Ionicons name="md-play-circle" size={24} color="black" />
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.control} onPress={nextTrack}>
          <Ionicons name="md-skip-forward" size={24} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

According to the icon directory, https://icons.expo.fyi/, I got all I need, but the icons don't render.

They appear as little boxes with X's in them.

How can I fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using the appropriate babel preset. initialize a new project and compare the babel.config.js with the one in your project